# Create Page When Category created/added programatically

Tags: wordpress, categories

I need to create wordpress page whenever a new category is added/created. I need to do it programatically, is there any hook/filter in wordpress to achieve such functionlaity, like save_post filter for posts.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the action hook [`created_$taxonomy`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2141). For the taxonomy Category:

```
add_action( 'created_category', function( $term_id, $tt_id )
{
    // The new category ID is $term_id
    // Use it to do your thing
}, 10, 2 );
```